# How can I email query results formatted in html from MSSQL 2000 server?

Tags: sql-server-2000, database-mail

The only system SP I have is master.dbo.xp_smtp_sendmail and I can't make it work (or I just don't know how).  I cannot upgrade the DB at this time.  I'm trying something like this:

```
@body_text=N'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM payhistory WHERE entered BETWEEN 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) 
AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4) AND desk=020 ORDER BY entered 
DESC

exec master.dbo.xp_smtp_sendmail
@server = 'server',
@from = 'administrator@mydomain.com', 
@to = 'me@mydomain.com', 
@subject = 'HTML Testing...', 
@type = 'text/html', 
@message = @body_text
```

I can do this easily in 2005 and up using "msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail" but I am stuck on 2000 due to the size of the DB for now.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Justin, please take the [tour].  Also, are you getting an error?

Comment: You are running a very primitive version of sql server that is totally out of support. Highly recommend you to upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing an apostrophe from the end of the `@body_text` parameter.  This fixes that problem:

```
@body_text=N'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM payhistory WHERE entered BETWEEN 
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) 
AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4) AND desk=020 ORDER BY entered 
DESC';

exec master.dbo.xp_smtp_sendmail
    @server = 'server',
    @from = 'administrator@mydomain.com', 
    @to = 'me@mydomain.com', 
    @subject = 'HTML Testing...', 
    @type = 'text/html', 
    @message = @body_text;
```

Also, You might consider using `xp_sendmail` from SQL Server 2000.  The syntax is:

```
EXEC xp_sendmail @recipients = 'recipients' 
      , @message = 'message'  
      , @query = 'query'  
      , @attachments = 'attachments  ;...n '  
      , @copy_recipients = 'copy_recipients  ;...n '
      , @blind_copy_recipients = 'blind_copy_recipients  ;...n '
      , @subject = 'subject' 
      , @type = 'type'  
      , @attach_results = 'attach_value' 
      , @no_output = 'output_value'  
      , @no_header = 'header_value'  
      , @width = width  
      , @separator = 'separator'  
      , @echo_error = 'echo_value'  
      , @set_user = 'user'  
      , @dbuse = 'database'
```

Of course, `xp_sendmail` requires an Outlook profile be setup on the server, which might be prohibitive.